# how to change the us number notation to indian number notation of bar chart in pentaho dashboard

Tags: graph, pentaho

I want to change the bar chart y axis amount format to Indian number notation. Presently the graph looks like this...[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNquc.png) is there any way to change this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property to change is the **Ortho Axis Tick Formatter**.

That property accepts a function and will apply it to all the tick mark values. Pentaho also has a method for that in the Utils class, which I used.

Here is mine for dutch formatting:

```
function f(v) {return Utils.numberFormat(v, '#,###.#','nl-nl');}
```

- parameter 1 is v, the value being processed
- parameter 2 is the format to use
- parameter 3 is the regional setting to use

To apply this to all charts on the dashboard, refer to the [blog by Diethard Steiner](http://diethardsteiner.github.io/ctools/2015/03/23/CDE-Global-CCC-Properties.html)